# How to use Mac OS X Cocoa events for multitouch gestures

Tags: cocoa, osx-leopard

I'm writing a program that has an NSView embedded in an NSScrollView which user can zoom. I'd love to set it up so the user can zoom the view using the multitouch pinch gesture supported on MacBook Air and the new unibody MacBooks/MacBooks Pro and in applications like Safari and iPhoto. I've hunted through Apple's documentation and can't figure out how do to this.

1. Is this supported using publicly available APIs on Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard?
2. If not, how "bad" are the private APIs (e.g. is it just an undeclared constant or a whole new set of methods)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** Snow Leopard adds supported APIs for gestures and multi-touch. See the [AppKit release notes for Snow Leopard](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html#X10_6Notes); ⌘F for “gesture” and “MultiTouch” (sic). They'll look pretty familiar if you've used ones below, but there probably are some fine differences, so read the new documentation anyway.

---

> Is this supported using publicly available APIs on Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard?

No. 10.5.0 doesn't support it at all, and 10.5.1 through 10.5.6 make you implement undocumented methods.

> If not, how "bad" are the private APIs (e.g. is it just an undeclared constant or a whole new set of methods)?

Not bad at all. [You have to implement some undocumented event methods in your view.](http://web.archive.org/web/20090618162428/http://cocoadex.com/2008/02/nsevent-modifications-swipe-ro.html) Since *you're* the one implementing the methods, you shouldn't crash if Apple changes the methods; all that will happen is the feature will stop working.

However, if you'll be retrieving the absolute (not delta) magnification or rotation from the event, then those are as-yet-undocumented methods of the event, so you should guard those messages with `respondsToSelector:` messages and perform careful range-checking on the methods' return values.

Comment: @x3ro, instead of editing it to relocate the "Edit" notice, which is a trivial personal aesthetic matter, why didn't you edit it to remove the link to the undocumented event methods since it's now 404?

Comment: Because I didn't even click it, which makes sense, because I dismissed the answer at first, because I thought it was only covering Mac OS X 10.5. When revisiting the answer later, I saw the Edit at the bottom, which is why I moved it to the top, so people see the updated information right away. Is that really a "trivial personal aesthetic matter"? Do you start reading at the bottom?